# WP Gutenberg: create a block which hosts standard blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Hello  here is my first post..

I'd like to know if there is a way to create blocks for Gutenberg that hosts other standard gutenberg block?

Imagine that I want to create a custom card...
My block would have a title  (richText component), a picture (Image component) and then a 'zone' where the user could drop any (compatible) block he wants: header, paragraph, list, quote, image .... and so on

What kind of block this 'zone' could it be? I can't figure that for the moment.

I want to reproduce the same scenario from columns block: when you insert a column block, you can after insert into it any block you want with the + button...

Thanks